# How to Consume WebApi WebService that Requires Redirect for Login

Tags: c#, xml, web-services, asp.net-web-api

We have a desktop application that requires authentication with a server in order to operate.  This application prepares and sends a query to a webservice, the user is prompted from this webservice to log in and the webservice returns an XML document with application subscription information (Software-as-a-Service Subscription License).

I've created a WebApi webservice that does the following:

1. Accept incoming request at /api/client?[MACHINEINFOINQUERYSTRING]
2. Redirect to external authentication provider (think GoogleId or
   similar)
3. Authentication provider sends information back to
   /api/subscription/[AUTHENTICATIONID]
4. The /api/subscription endpoint returns an XML document after pulling info from the servers (or including appropriate error message).

This webservice works and the XML document can be viewed in the browser.  I've created a website with a default.aspx to test this, automatically redirecting to the /api/client and it does display this XML document in the browser.

The desktop application properly makes the initial call, redirects through an embedded browser to the login page, and receives an XML, but this XML cannot be parsed.  The application team simply gets a "download" option for the XML but cannot capture the response for stuffing into an XmlDocument object.  I've attempted to create an example application to instruct the app team, but have had no success.

Questions:

- Do I have this architecture fundamentally wrong or do we simply not know how to consume the response properly?
- How do I capture and consume the XML that is successfully returned?

As an example of what I've tried:

```
string requestString = string.Format("http://[server]/api/client?{0}", HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(queryString));
Response.Redirect(requestString);
```

This works in the browser, displays the login page, allows for input, redirects to the subscription endpoint which then prepares and delivers the XML to the browser.  Unfortunately, this is unusable by a consumer.

```
HttpWebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(requestString) as HttpWebRequest;
request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
request.MaximumAutomaticRedirections = 20;
request.AuthenticationLevel = System.Net.Security.AuthenticationLevel.None;
HttpWebResponse response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

This doesn't work.  The response.ResponseUri has the properly formatted address of the OAuth service (step 2 above).  It does not display the login page to the user even though this is all initiated through a browser.

I've also tried using a WebRequest POST, HttpClient PostAsync and several other methods, but:

The response URL is simply the location of the login page.  If I string together 3 WebRequest/WebResponse pairs, it fails because the user isn't being properly authenticated at the first request / initial redirect.

What does work in my default.aspx:

I haven't found an example online for my specific needs, but the pattern must exist in practice as plenty of websites utilize OAuth style logins. I've utilized webservices (like OData endpoints) that also require logins, so this pattern must exist for webservices too.  I do send back a properly formatted XML document.  We just don't know how to capture and consume that document.

Any examples of a similar architecture would be highly appreciated! Or pointing me in the right direction.

Edit ---
I'm thinking that somehow the request.GetResponse() isn't really allowing for redirects and/or since it's an HttpWebRequest, there's no way it will allow for user input.

What's the proper way to make this call and consume the XML from another application?  the XML is delivered properly in a browser window (with Response.Redirect) but no login window opens using an HttpWebRequest.

Comment: Where is your XML Serializer Class? Did you even Implement it?

Comment: Sorry, didn't think it was relevant:  Global.ascx.cx registers the XmlFormatter. The "subscription" class will successfully serialize in a correct parsable XML.  The "client" class doesn't serialize (it can, but I'm using the public IHttpActionResult GetClient() interface which returns either OK, or in this instance a redirect.  If the incoming data is bad, it returns an OK with a properly formatted Client XML object including error information.  I've also tried returning a RedirectResult, but that' doesn't trigger a redirect from the WebRequest.

Comment: can you add response value in your question?

Comment: I just want to add, Your way does work. But there is a better way. Lets check the response and just move ahead of what you have.

Comment: Try using a sniffer like wireshark or fiddler to capture donwload.  The last data packet should contain a 200 Done status if successful, otherwise, a failure message.  Usually failure occurs because of mis-matches in the HTML headers.  You may also be able to capture xml data which you can verify.  Simple method of checking xml is to use VS menu : Project : Add New item : XML.  Then paste your xml into window.  Errors will show up in Error List like any other compiler errors.

Comment: Thanks for your help Aizen, I've updated accordingly. My original attempt used Response.Redirect and "seemed" to provide everything perfectly, a resultant proper XML was returned.  Case closed, so I thought.  Problem is doing anything with this XML.  I created a webservice that can't be consumed, only seen in the browser.  By using a WebRequest, it doesn't actually do the redirect and tell my server to await a response from somewhere else.  What I don't understand is why it works with redirects but not when I'm trying to consume that XML.

Comment: HI jdweng.  XML is valid.  Fiddler shows the sequence mentioned in the list above:  1) query to /api/client?[something] (302), 2) query to OAuth provider (200), 3) query to /api/subscription/[ID] (200).  Response in correct format.  <Subscription xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"><...  But only when I use the Response.Redirect(step 1) method.  Using WebRequest stops at step 1, with a 200 result.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is:  This architecture is fundamentally wrong.

OAuth architecture leaves the authorization to the client, which then sends an authorization token to all subsequent services that it requires.  The services are simple endpoints and do not contain any authentication logic, (although the service itself is allowed to validate the authentication token with the OAuth server).

The proper sequence of events for this answer should be:
1) Desktop Application makes OAuth authentication request to authentication server.
2) A successful response includes an authorization token which contains identity information, permissions, validity period, etc.
3) The desktop app then requests information from the WebApi service, sending in the request that token.
4) WebApi takes this authentication token, validates it (in my case against a certificate) and may even query the OAuth server again to ensure that the token is still valid.
5) If valid, the web service gathers the data and sends it back to the server.

My problem was I was expecting the subscription service itself to be able to open a web browser, prompt for a login, and then continue the request to another endpoint (2 redirects after initial request).  I was in effect, breaking both the WebApi and OAuth 2 designs.  Although it worked from the browser, it was not consumable from an application.

After redesigning to this simpler pattern, my web service is now consumable.